# How to call a Java Rest API from PHP Codeigniter Controller?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a rest service written in Spring MVC. The requirement is to call the particular service from my Codeigniter project. Here is the code I used,

```
function connection(){
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        $endpoint  = "http://localhost:8090/{projectName}/{rest_endpoint}";

        try
        {
            // Get cURL resource
            $curl = curl_init();
            // Set some options
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Accept:application/json']
            ));
            // Send the request & save response to $resp
            $resp = curl_exec($curl);

            // Check HTTP status code
            if (!curl_errno($curl)) {
                switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
                    case 200:  # OK
                        echo "Server JSON Response:" . $resp;
                        break;
                    default:
                        echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";
                        echo $resp;
                }
            }
            // Close request to clear up some resources
            curl_close($curl);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {

            printf("Error while sending request, reason: %s\n",$ex->getMessage());

        }
    }
```

This does not call the Rest endpoint. Both of them are running on localhost.

Comment: You never mentioned, if you got any response code in return from the rest service. If its a GET request did you try opening from browser as a step#1 test.

Comment: It gives correct response in the browser. When the same request is made via code, it displays HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request but never calls rest API because API is in debugging mode and must wait in debug points.

Comment: Well if it's 400 it definitely went to the server, but only failed in the framework itself rather than actually reaching till your java code. I am no expert in codeigniter, but would recommend checking the request being sent to the rest API from your code to see for any possible issues. You can use Wireshark or Fiddler to intercept the request. Hope this helps.